# How to convert char to int?

Tags: c#, .net

What is the proper way to convert a `char` to `int`?
This gives `49`:

```
int val = Convert.ToInt32('1');
//int val = Int32.Parse("1"); // Works
```

I don't want to convert to string and then parse it.

Answer (score 299, accepted):

I'm surprised nobody has mentioned the static method built right into `System.Char`...

```
int val = (int)Char.GetNumericValue('8');
// val == 8
```

Comment: Good spot! +1 Very odd that it returns a `double`, though

Comment: I agree, I can't figure out why it returns 'double' - how can a single character possibly represent a floating-point number?

Comment: There are many Unicode characters that do represent a non-integer number, e.g., [U+2153](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2153/index.htm).

Comment: @dtb - I hadn't considered that. `Char.GetNumericValue('⅓')` does indeed return `0.3333...`. Thanks for pointing that out!

Comment: Does inverse function exist?

Comment: Foot Note: this function is currently not available in NetMF.

Answer (score 40):

how about (for `char c`)

```
int i = (int)(c - '0');
```

which does substraction of the char value?

Re the API question (comments), perhaps an extension method?

```
public static class CharExtensions {
    public static int ParseInt32(this char value) {
        int i = (int)(value - '0');
        if (i < 0 || i > 9) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("value");
        return i;
    }
}
```

then use `int x = c.ParseInt32();`

Comment: I should have mentioned, I knew about this but is there any other way? I wanted to know if there is an API to do this?

Comment: If you want a bahavior similiar to `int.Parse`, i.e. that an exception is thrown on invalid input you would need to add additional bounds checking: `if (i < 0 || i > 9) throw new FormatException();`

Comment: @user386338 I'm afraid that there is not.

Comment: @user386338 - updated with *an* option re API, also including @0xA3's feedback

Comment: @user386338 - see Joel's answer for an inbuilt API method

Comment: So.. Which should I use? `(int)Char.GetNumericValue(ch);` or `(int)(c - '0');` or `c & 0x0f` (probably faster) ?

Comment: @Jack if you are after faster, then time it (using large numbers of iterations) and you'll have your answer

Answer (score 21):

What everyone is forgeting is explaining WHY this happens.

A Char, is basically an integer, but with a pointer in the ASCII table. All characters have a corresponding integer value as you can clearly see when trying to parse it.

Pranay has clearly a different character set, thats why HIS code doesnt work. 
the only way is

```
int val = '1' - '0';
```

because this looks up the integer value in the table of `'0'` which is then the 'base value' 
subtracting your number in char format from this will give you the original number.

Answer (score 16):

```
int i = (int)char.GetNumericValue(c);
```

Yet another option:

```
int i = c & 0x0f;
```

This should accomplish this as well.

Answer (score 4):

```
int val = '1' - '0';
```

This can be done using ascii codes where '0' is the lowest and the number characters count up from there

Comment: This is brilliant! imo the most elegant solution here.

Answer (score 3):

```
int val = '1' - 48;
```

Comment: @Luke Xu : '0' has ASCII code 0x30 which is 48 in decimal so this is the same as '1' - '0'

Answer (score 3):

You may use the following extension method:

```
public static class CharExtensions
    {
        public static int CharToInt(this char c)
        {
            if (c < '0' || c > '9')
                throw new ArgumentException("The character should be a number", "c");

            return c - '0';
        }
    }
```

Comment: @0xA3 The range check has to be at the beginning of the method in general. Semantically if we are to convert `char` to `int` we have to check range of the input parameter, not the output `int` value.

Comment: There is no need to check result `int` value because the range of numeric chars was performed at the start of the method, so there will be correct resulting value, if specified char is not in the range of numeric chars there will be thrown exception. The same logic as you provided but range check is performed at the beginning of the method.

Comment: Sorry, I was misreading your code sample. Sometimes it's hard to see the most obvious things. I'd bet that the code said `if (c < 0 || c > 9)`...

Answer (score 1):

The most secure way to accomplish this is using Int32.TryParse method. See here:
http://dotnetperls.com/int-tryparse

Comment: TryParse is for strings not for chars

Comment: Yes it is but stille the most secure way to accomplish the conversion

Comment: Converting a single character to an integer is a security matter?

Comment: 'Secure' in this case means that it won't cause problems if your char isn't actually an ascii number - it could be a multi-byte unicode character.

Answer (score 1):

```
int val = '1' & 15;
```

The binary of the ASCII charecters 0-9 is:

0   -   00110000

1   -   00110001

2   -   00110010

3   -   00110011

4   -   00110100

5   -   00110101

6   -   00110110

7   -   00110111

8   -   00111000

9   -   00111001

and if you take in each one of them the first 4 LSB(using bitwise AND with 8'b00001111 that equels to 15) you get the actual number (0000 = 0,0001=1,0010=2,... )

Comment: How does this work in terms of types? you are using a bitwise operator between a char and an int and then returns an int? Does the logical AND uses the binary representation of both the char and the int and return a binary representation and then as you are defining the var as an int it uses that representation?

Comment: @mitnomed yes and if you use byte for example then it uses the byte representation.

Answer (score 0):

An extension of some other answers that covers hexadecimal representation:

```
public int CharToInt(char c) 
{
    if (c >= '0' && c <= '9') 
    {
        return c - '0';
    }
    else if (c >= 'a' && c <= 'f') 
    {
        return 10 + c - 'a';
    }
    else if (c >= 'A' && c <= 'F') 
    {
        return 10 + c - 'A';
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
int val = Convert.ToInt32("" + '1');
```

Comment: why not just .ToString()?

Comment: @Veikedo he wants an int, and not a string.

Comment: I mean `Convert.ToInt32('1'.ToString())`