# C#: Converting int to string and checking for characters in the string

Tags: c#, type-conversion

In a C# console application I want to convert an int to a string, then check the characters in the new string, and convert them to and int. This is what I have so far to do that:

```
    int charNum = 0;
    int value = 111
    string valueStr = value.ToString();
    int numVariant = valueStr.ToCharArray()[charNum];
```

Then I add this to output their values

```
    Console.WriteLine(numVariant + " " + valueStr + " " + charNum);
    Console.ReadLine();
```

And strangely it returns

```
    49 111 0
```

Whereas what I expected it to return is

```
  1 111 0
```

So what I assume is something went wrong with converting the char to a int, any suggestions on how to fix this?

Comment: `int numVariant = valueStr.ToCharArray()[charNum] - '0';`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [c# why does this return 49: Convert.ToInt32('1')](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665978/c-sharp-why-does-this-return-49-convert-toint321)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

49 is the character of '1's ascii decimal value. It is storing that because you are assigning the value to an int32 and the compiler is automatically casting the value. Simply change:

```
int numVariant = valueStr.ToCharArray()[charNum];
```

To:

```
char numVariant = valueStr.ToCharArray()[charNum];
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `int numVariant = valueStr.ToCharArray()[charNum];`
with
`int numVariant = int.Parse(valueStr[charNum].ToString());`

Otherwise it takes the ASCII value of 1

Comment: This worked perfectly, but turns out for what I'm working, on a char value would be better, thanks a bunch for the response though :)

Comment: Maybe, but your questions says that you want to convert it back to an `int`.

Comment: Yeah, that was my bad, sorry about that