# Char array is returning incorrect values

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a char array, `chars[]` with values `{'#', '$', '1'}` contained within it. I want to remove the `1` and place it into another variable, `val`, but when I do it gives me a 49 (idk why). I tried debugging it and the info shows that the elements of `chars` are as follows:

```
char[0] = 35 '#'
char[1] = 36 '$'
char[2] = 49 '1'
```

Which in turn makes

```
int val = char[2];
```

become

```
val = 49
```

I'm not sure why this is, but it's throwing my plans off. Does anyone know what the problem is and what I can do to fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use 
`char val = char[2];`

With int, you are getting the ASCII representation of the char as an integer.
see also http://hu.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Comment: I've run into a problem with this. Now it results in `val = 49 '1'`. Is there a way to just get `1`?

Comment: The debugger may show `val = 49 '1'` but as long as the data type is a `char` in the system, it should work fine giving you the character '1' where needed.

Comment: @markwdickson Understood. So if I run a function on `val` to convert `1` into an int should I still get 1?

Comment: Just did it. `int val = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(char[2]);` gave me what I was looking for. 

For future reference:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665757/c-sharp-convert-char-to-int

Answer (score 1):

49 is the ASCII representation for the char '1'

[link](http://web.cs.mun.ca/~michael/c/ascii-table.html) to ASCII table

Comment: You know what? As I was editing my question I realized that I'm trying to place a char into an int variable. I believe that is my problem.

Comment: Yeah the char at address 1 != the character `1`

Answer (score 0):

Just go for: `charArray[x].ToString();`

This will convert the ASCII representation to an actual Character.

Comment: Super late but hey.