# If and Else if block only runs the Else if

Tags: c#, if-statement

It would seem like this whole simple code is correct, but when I click start and type in any number such as 4 or 6, the only output is the "else if" every time!

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace ConsoleApplication6
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
            if (c >= 0  && c < 5)
            {
                Console.Write("# is > 0");
            } 
            else if (c >= 5)
            {
                Console.Write("# is > 5");
            }
            Console.ReadKey();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you debug put a breakpoint and see what the value of c actually is?

Comment: Don't use the `Convert` class, use either `ToString` or `TryParse` or a cast depending on what you want.  These all-in-one "DWIM" APIs always fail (to do what you mean, they don't necessarily crash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `Console.Read` is the problem here. It returns an `int` that represents the ASCII value of the next key that is pressed. For the character '4' for example, that's **52**. `Convert.ToInt32` will just return the passed value when passed an `int`, so thats the value of `c`.

If your code was

```
        int c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Then it would work as expected, as `Console.ReadLine()` returns a string. You could also do:

```
        int c = Convert.ToInt32(((char)Console.Read()).ToString());
```

Note that I am casting the 52 returned to a `char` which would then actually be parsed after calling `ToString` on it.

Answer (score 5):

[`Console.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) reads:

> The next character from the input stream, [...]

If you look at the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com/), you will notice that characters representing digits have values starting from 48. The value you're getting is already an integer, so there is nothing to convert (see `Console.Read` signature in the documentation). As suggested by [Travis J](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1026459/travis-j), you can use the following code, to get the expected result:

```
int c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

As you may see in [the documentation for `Console.ReadLine`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) - it returns a `string`.

Consider using the debugger, as suggested in the comments under your question, along with reading the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

The problem here is that you are taking input as an ascii character. So you end up with the ascii value. For example, when 4 is entered, 52 is the integer representation of that character and that is the value returned from the `.Read`.

The value is a char value (int) because you are only using `.Read`. If you change it to `.ReadLine` it will come in as a string and properly cast to an int.

```
int c = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
```

Comment: Technically, it actually returns an `int` (not `char` https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) Granted, that int is the ASCII value of the character :)

Answer (score 1):

```
Console.Read();
```

gets the next character user inputs.
You have used

```
Convert.ToInt32(Console.Read());
```

This returns the ASCII value of the number(taken as a character input).For '0' it's 48,for '1' it's 49.this explains why your code always goes into else if.
Instead use this :

```
int val = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(Console.Read())
```

This val shall store the accurate int value.It's mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665757/how-to-convert-char-to-int)