# Converting a string getting Wrong value

Tags: c#

I write a simple code and need to get each number in a string as an Integer
But when I try to use **Convert.ToInt32()** it give me another value

**Example:**

```
string x="4567";        
Console.WriteLine(x[0]);
```

the result will be **4** , but if i try to use Convert

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(x[0]));
```

it Give me **52** !!

I try using  int.TryParse() and its the same

Comment: The ascii value of 4 is 52. http://www.theasciicode.com.ar/ascii-printable-characters/number-four-ascii-code-52.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665757/how-to-convert-char-to-int

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the docs:

> The ToInt32(Char) method returns a 32-bit signed integer that represents the UTF-16 encoded code unit of the value argument. If value is not a low surrogate or a high surrogate, this return value also represents the Unicode code point of value.

In order to get 4, you'd have to convert it to a string before converting to int32:

```
Console.WriteLine(Convert.ToInt32(x[0].ToString()));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can alternatively do this way to loop through all characters in a string

```
foreach (char c in x)
{
    Console.WriteLine(c);  
}
```

Will Print 4,5,6,7

And as suggested in earlier answer before converting to integer make that as a sting so it doesn't return the ascii code

Answer (score 0):

A `char` is internally a `short integer` of it's `ASCII` representation.

If you cast/convert (explicitly or implicitly) a char to int, you will get it's Ascii value. Example `Convert.ToInt32('4')` = `52`

But when you print it to Console, you are using it's ToString() method implicitly, so you are actually printing the `ASCII` character '4'. Example: Console.WriteLine(x[0]) is equivalent to Console.WriteLine("4")

Try using an `ASCII` letter so you will notice the difference clearly:

```
            Console.WriteLine((char)('a'));  // a
            Console.WriteLine((int)('a'));   // 97
```

Now play with `char` math:

```
            Console.WriteLine((char)('a'+5));  // f
            Console.WriteLine((int)('a'+5));   // 102
```

Bottom line, just use `int digit = int.Parse(x[0]);`

Or the funny (but less secure) way: `int digit = x[0] - '0';`

Answer (score -1):

x isnt x[0], x[0] is the first char, '4' which is 52.

Comment: what shall i do to get the 4 ?

Comment: Convert.ToInt32(x.Substring(0, 1));