# Main Menu for a mastermind game

Tags: c#

I am trying to create the menu for a mastermind game which can be ran in a command prompt using C#. The issue I am running into is capturing the users input for the menu. If they enter a 2 then it should display that they entered the number two and if not then it would say they have not displayed the number two.

The issue I am having is that it wont turn the users input into a working integer and will either come up saying that it can't explicitly convert from System.ConsoleKeyInfo to int or string to int.

```
using System;

namespace MasterMind
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Green;
            Console.WriteLine("               MasterMind's Main Menu");
            Console.WriteLine("                    1: Play");
            Console.WriteLine("                    2: Help");
            Console.WriteLine("                    0: Exit");
            int userinput = Console.ReadKey();
            if (Nuserinput == 2);
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is a number 2");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("This is not a number 2");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `Console.ReadKey()` returns `ConsoleKeyInfo` not an `int`.

Comment: Console.ReadKey() Doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: Please just read the documentation online for `Console.ReadKey()`. It does not do what you think. (and this has been asked many times).

Comment: ConsoleKeyInfo Doc: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo.keychar(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Char to Int info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665757/how-to-convert-char-to-int

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your

```
int userinput = Console.ReadKey();
if (Nuserinput == 2)
```

To:

```
string userInput = Console.ReadKey().KeyChar.ToString();
if(input == "2")
```

Or covert the string to an int as shown in other answers. But for this, a string works fine.

Answer (score 5):

`Console.ReadKey()` [returns a `ConsoleKeyInfo` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85.aspx), which is not an `int` object.  You can get a `char` from that, for example:

```
var key = Console.ReadKey();
var keyChar = key.KeyChar;
```

If you expect that `char` value to represent an integer, you can convert it to one:

```
int keyInt = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(keyChar);
```

Aside from other error checking you might want to put in place in case the user *doesn't* enter a valid integer, this would at least get your the integer value you're looking for.

Answer (score 3):

[`Console.ReadKey()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/471w8d85(v=vs.110).aspx) returns  a [`ConsoleKeyInfo`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.consolekeyinfo(v=vs.110).aspx), so you'll need to do something like this:

```
ConsoleKeyInfo data = Console.ReadKey();
int num;
if (int.TryParse(data.KeyChar.ToString(), out num) && num == 2)
{
    Console.WriteLine("This is a number 2");
}else{
    Console.WriteLine("This is not a number 2");
}
```