# The given key was not present in the dictionary. c#

Tags: c#, dictionary, exception

i want to use `Dictionary` and `Action` to call some static method
here is my code:

```
public class  Works
{

    public static void DoWorkA()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Doing Work A");
    }
    public static void DoWorkB()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(2000);
        Console.WriteLine("Doing Work B");
    }
    public static void DoWorkC()
    {
        Thread.Sleep(3000);
        Console.WriteLine("Doing Work C");
    }
}
```

and this is is my main method

```
 try
        {
            var DoJob = new Dictionary<int, Action>();
            DoJob.Add(1, () => Works.DoWorkA());
            DoJob.Add(2, () => Works.DoWorkB());
            DoJob.Add(3, () => Works.DoWorkC());

            var input = Console.Read();
            var job = DoJob[input];
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);

        }
        Console.ReadKey();
```

i use `foreach` to iterate keys and keys are exist

```
 foreach (var item in DoJob)
            {
                Console.WriteLine($"Item {item.Key} has Value {item.Value}");
            }
```

[image: Dictionary keys showed]

but when i want to access key using input value i get exception

[image]

whats wrong?

Comment: Just a wild guess, but I'm thinking the key you're using is not present in the dictionary.

Comment: `Console.Read` is returning `char`, e.g '1', '2', '3' which is not the same as `int` 1, 2, 3

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665757/how-to-convert-char-to-int

Comment: @CodeCaster I read it as `ReadLine` (ie, a string)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[`Console.Read`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a character code, not the actual value.

For instance, if you type "1", `Console.Read` will return 49.

You need some conversion to retrieve the desired value as an int:

```
var input = Console.Read();
var job = DoJob[CharUnicodeInfo.GetDecimalDigitValue((char)input)];
```

Answer (score 1):

Console.Read() returns the int value of the next character from input stream, the value of character '1' is not 1, hence the exception.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.read(v=vs.110).aspx

You can convert the char to int using <strike>Convert.ToInt32(input)</strike> CharUnicodeInfo.GetDecimalDigitValue((char)input) as suggested in answer by Kevin https://stackoverflow.com/a/44735459/7970673

Comment: What you're thinking of would be a compile error. What you're suggesting doesn't fix the issue, the char `'1'` converts to the int `49`: http://ideone.com/SpWNqA

Comment: yes, my bad. The fix I suggested earlier wouldn't have worked. Hence updated my answer