# string of integers to int[] array C#

Tags: c#, arrays, console-application

This question is different as it tackles the issue of converting a char to an int when adding to an integer array.

The following piece of code, I am trying to implement a string of integers into a int[] array in C#.

My desired output is an array of:

```
12345678910
```

This is my code, however, the output of this is not what I desire:

```
string numbers = "12345678910";

int[] array = new int[numbers.Length];

for (int i = 1; i <= numbers.Length; i++)
{
    array[i - 1] = numbers[i-1];
}

foreach(var y in array)
{
    Console.Write(y);
}
```

Output of given code:

```
4950515253545556574948
```

Can somebode tell me why I am getting this output, and what I can do to fix this? Thank you!

Edit: Changed my code and it works using this:

```
for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++)
{
     array[i] = int.Parse(numbers[i].ToString());
}
```

Comment: You are converting each character to its code and then displaying the code, not the associated digit

Comment: Strings are arrays of *char* objects. What you see are the numeric values of individual characters.

Comment: Do you want an array that looks like this? `int[] array = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 1, 0 }`?

Comment: I see! Yes Robert!

Comment: Then you need to loop character by character through the string and use `int.Parse` to turn each character into a number.

Comment: okay I'll give that a try, thanks!

Comment: Digits come one after another and `Char` objects can be converted to `int` implicitly. You could use `numbers.Select(c=>(int)c-'0').ToArray()` to get an array of numbers from the string.

Comment: Quick side note: Your `for` loop is unnecessarily redundant. `for (int i = 1; i <= numbers.Length; i++) array[i - 1] = numbers[i-1];` can be written a lot easier such as `for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++) array[i] = numbers[i];` -- Using this approach, you don't have to remember to put `i-1` in every index accessor.

Comment: Also if you code your for loop as `for (int i = 0; i < numbers.Length; i++` you don't have to do the whole `i - 1` to get the right index

Comment: Thank you for the tips everyone!

Comment: http://www.asciitable.com/

Comment: int[] array = numbers.Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(Char.GetNumericValue(x))).ToArray();

Comment: I have added an update to my question with a solution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, I don't think you'll be able to distinguish a two digit number using this method.

I refer to this part of your code: `string numbers = "123456789`**`10`**`";`
Iterate through your string characters and parse to Int (if that's what's required) ([credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1019793/how-can-i-convert-string-to-int)) ([credit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3665757/how-to-convert-char-to-int/3666138))

```
 foreach (char character in yourString)
        {
            int x = (int)Char.GetNumericValue(character);                
            //code to add to your array of ints
        }
```